# RC4 implementation in C

Tags: c, cryptography

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>


typedef uint8_t byte;
typedef struct
{
    byte i, j;
    byte S[256];
} Rc4State;

void swap(byte *a, byte *b)
{
    byte temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

/*Initialization & initial permutation
also initialize i&j counters in state for stream generation*/
void initState(const byte K[256], int keylen, Rc4State *state)
{
    byte T[256];
    assert(keylen>=1 && keylen<=256);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        state-> S[i] = i;
        T[i] = K[i % keylen];
    }

    //Initial permutation of S
    byte *S = state->S;
    int j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        j = (j + S[i] + T[i]) % 256;
        swap(&S[i], &S[j]);
    }

    //Initialize counters in state
    state->i = state->j = 0;
}

/*Encrypt/Decrypt text by XORing with next byte of keystream*/
byte crypt(byte text, Rc4State *state)
{
    byte t, k;
    byte *i = &(state->i), *j = &(state->j);
    byte *S = state->S;
    *i = (*i+1) % 256;
    *j = (*j+S[*i]) % 256;
    swap(&S[*i], &S[*j]);
    t = (S[*i] + S[*j]) % 256;
    k = S[t];

    return text ^ k;
}
```

I considered removing the `%256` since it's implied in unsigned 8 bit arithmetic but left it in for clarity.

[I asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611184/is-arithmetic-overflow-equivalent-to-modulo-operation).

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From top to bottom…

- `#include <stdio.h>` appears to be left over from development, and can be removed.
- `swap()` is not part of your library's interface, and should be declared `static`.
- To give your library a sense of unity, I'd rename `initState()` → `rc4InitState()` and `crypt()` → `rc4Crypt()`.  The latter renaming is also important so as not to clash with the traditional Unix [`crypt(3)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(Unix)) function.  Also for consistency, I'd make `Rc4State *state` the first parameter of each function.
- Assertions are not really an appropriate mechanism for parameter validation.  The use of `assert()` in `initState()` is marginal.  You should assert conditions that you *know* to be true, rather than conditions that you *hope* to be true.  Alternatively stated, assertion failures should arise from programmer errors, not user errors.

  Change `int keylen` to `uint8_t keylen`, and most of the validation problem goes away anyway.  (In C, `i % 0` has undefined behaviour.)
- On the other hand, you *could* add an `assert((byte)(S[i] + 256) == S[i])` to put to rest your concerns about overflow.
- Calling `crypt()` to encrypt a byte at a time is inefficient.  The function should accept a byte array and length.  A compiler might inline a function, but if you're writing this as a library, the linker can't optimize away a function call.
- `*i` and `*j` are a bit unconventional for my taste.  Here's how I would express it:

  ```
  static byte rc4CryptByte(Rc4State *state, byte plainText)
  {
      byte *S = state->S;
      byte i = ++(state->i);
      byte j = (state->j += S[i]);

      swap(&S[i], &S[j]);
      byte t = S[i] + S[j];
      byte k = S[t];

      return plainText ^ k;
  }

  void rc4Crypt(Rc4State *state, byte text[], size_t len)
  {
      for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
      {
          text[i] = rc4CryptByte(state, text[i]);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Actually, I wasn't implementing a library and I just copy pasted everything except the `main()` from my program.

Comment: It would still be a good habit to write your code as if you were designing a library. The best practices I suggested cost you nothing.

Comment: Of course, I was simply clarifying. The main motive in posting to CR was to make a habit of following best practices.Thanks for the part on assert & static esp.
Also, I don't think I can make `keylen` as `uint8_t` as it won't be able to take the value 256.